# Why Clang cannot find Boost Libraries Despite Being Added to the PATH?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, boost, clang

I am trying to include `Boost` Libraries in my C++ script after installing it, but I am getting the following error message by the intellisense:

```
#include <boost/iterator/counting_iterator.hpp>

'boost/iterator/counting_iterator.hpp' file not found clang(pp_file_not_found)
```

I have attempted to look into the existing/similar questions on SO but none of them seem to help me figuring this out. I have gone through all steps of configuring my vscode for C++ development and I already can compile, link, build, and run c++ codes but as soon as I want to use boost libraries, the intellisence start to throw errors. Here are my configuration files in the vscode:

tasks.json

```
{
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "label": "build myfile",
      "type": "shell",
      "command": "g++",
      "args": [
        "-std=c++14",
        "-g",
        "-o",
        "${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
        "${fileBasename}",
        "-I",
        "C:/Program Files/boost_1_84_0/include/boost-1_84",
        "-L",
        "C:/Program Files/boost_1_84_0/lib"
      ],
      "group": {
        "kind": "build",
        "isDefault": true
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

settings.json

```
{
  "files.associations": {
    "*.tcc": "cpp",
    "cctype": "cpp",
    "clocale": "cpp",
    "cstddef": "cpp",
    "cstdint": "cpp",
    "cstdio": "cpp",
    "cstdlib": "cpp",
    "cwchar": "cpp",
    "cwctype": "cpp",
    "exception": "cpp",
    "initializer_list": "cpp",
    "iosfwd": "cpp",
    "iostream": "cpp",
    "istream": "cpp",
    "limits": "cpp",
    "new": "cpp",
    "ostream": "cpp",
    "streambuf": "cpp",
    "type_traits": "cpp",
    "typeinfo": "cpp"
  },
  "C_Cpp_Runner.msvcBatchPath": "C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/VC/Auxiliary/Build/vcvarsall.bat",
  "C_Cpp_Runner.cCompilerPath": "gcc",
  "C_Cpp_Runner.cppCompilerPath": "g++",
  "C_Cpp_Runner.debuggerPath": "gdb",
  "C_Cpp_Runner.cStandard": "",
  "C_Cpp_Runner.cppStandard": "",
  "C_Cpp_Runner.useMsvc": false,
  "C_Cpp_Runner.warnings": [
    "-Wall",
    "-Wextra",
    "-Wpedantic",
    "-Wshadow",
    "-Wformat=2",
    "-Wcast-align",
    "-Wconversion",
    "-Wsign-conversion",
    "-Wnull-dereference"
  ],
  "C_Cpp_Runner.msvcWarnings": [
    "/W4",
    "/permissive-",
    "/w14242",
    "/w14287",
    "/w14296",
    "/w14311",
    "/w14826",
    "/w44062",
    "/w44242",
    "/w14905",
    "/w14906",
    "/w14263",
    "/w44265",
    "/w14928"
  ],
  "C_Cpp_Runner.enableWarnings": true,
  "C_Cpp_Runner.warningsAsError": false,
  "C_Cpp_Runner.compilerArgs": [],
  "C_Cpp_Runner.linkerArgs": [],
  "C_Cpp_Runner.includePaths": [
    "C:/Program Files/boost_1_84_0/include"
  ],
  "C_Cpp_Runner.includeSearch": [
    "*",
    "**/*"
  ],
  "C_Cpp_Runner.excludeSearch": [
    "**/build",
    "**/build/**",
    "**/.*",
    "**/.*/**",
    "**/.vscode",
    "**/.vscode/**"
  ],
  "C_Cpp_Runner.useAddressSanitizer": false,
  "C_Cpp_Runner.useUndefinedSanitizer": false,
  "C_Cpp_Runner.useLeakSanitizer": false,
  "C_Cpp_Runner.showCompilationTime": false,
  "C_Cpp_Runner.useLinkTimeOptimization": false,
  "C_Cpp_Runner.msvcSecureNoWarnings": false,
  "C_Cpp.default.cppStandard": ""
}
```

launch.json

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "(Windows) Launch",
      "type": "cppvsdbg",
      "request": "launch",
      "program": "${workspaceFolder}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
      "args": [],
      "stopAtEntry": false,
      "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
      "environment": [],
      "console": "externalTerminal"
    },
    {
      "name": "(Windows) Attach",
      "type": "cppvsdbg",
      "request": "attach",
      "processId": "${command:pickProcess}"
    },
    {
      "name": "C/C++ Runner: Debug Session",
      "type": "cppdbg",
      "request": "launch",
      "args": [],
      "stopAtEntry": false,
      "externalConsole": true,
      "cwd": "c:/Users/username/Projects/CPP/Workspaces/Script",
      "program": "c:/Users/username/Projects/CPP/Workspaces/Script/build/Debug/outDebug",
      "MIMode": "gdb",
      "miDebuggerPath": "gdb",
      "setupCommands": [
        {
          "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
          "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
          "ignoreFailures": true
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

and `c_cpp_properties.json`

```
{
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "windows-gcc-x64",
      "browse": {
        "path": [
          "${workspaceFolder}"
        ],
        "limitSymbolsToIncludedHeaders": true
      },
      "includePath": [
        "${workspaceFolder}/**",
        "C:/Program Files/boost_1_84_0/include"
      ],
      "defines": [
        "_DEBUG",
        "UNICODE",
        "_UNICODE"
      ],
      "compilerPath": "C:/mingw64/bin/gcc.exe",
      "cStandard": "${default}",
      "cppStandard": "${default}",
      "intelliSenseMode": "windows-gcc-x64"
    }
  ],
  "version": 4
}
```

I also added the following to `settings.json` with no success:

```
 "clangd.fallbackFlags": [
    "-I",
    "C:\\Program Files\\boost_1_84_0\\include\\boost-1_84"
  ]
```

Comment: Does the file `C:/Program Files/boost_1_84_0/include/boost-1_84/boost/iterator/counting_iterator.hpp` exist? If you specify `-Ipath1` and then do `#include <path2>`, a compiler will be looking for `path1/path2`. Double check your paths.

Comment: Yes, it exists.

Comment: Cmake or some other build system is the correct answer. The VS Code jsons stop being ideal once you move on from single file programs.

Comment: And why value of `"C_Cpp_Runner.includePaths"` is different from value of `"-I"`?

Comment: @Evg, I have no reason to do that other than trying suggestions from other similar answers.

Comment: You have different versions of the path in tasks.json and c_cpp_properties.json. Make up your mind. If as you say you have `C:/Program Files/boost_1_84_0/include/boost-1_84/boost/iterator/counting_iterator.hpp` then `"C:/Program Files/boost_1_84_0/include"` is obviously wrong.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI, I have tried matching them to "C:/Program Files/boost_1_84_0/include/boost-1_84" with no success.

Comment: I don't believe in miracles. Either there is a typo in the include search path, or you are using some extension that makes vscode ignore the path.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it makes sense, but I had to include the include path and libs in my Makefile under de CXXFLAGS.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: It's not clear. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: Do you have a Makefile in your project. If so  look for the CXXFLAGS, I've got something like this CXXFLAGS := -std=c++17 -Wall -Wextra -g -I/usr/local/lib  -lncurses -ljsoncpp -L/usr/local/lib/ -lfltk  -I/opt/homebrew/Cellar/fltk/1.3.8_1/include -I/opt/homebrew/Cellar/jsoncpp/1.9.5/include/ -I/opt/hombrew/include -L/opt/homebrew/lib
With the -I option you can include the include libraries, and with the -L flags your libs.

Answer (score -3):

try this ways to adress folder

put an attached double \ \ and not a /

Comment: Your suggestion didn't work.

Comment: And there is no reason why it should. You certainly haven’t given one.